# Working out payoff of a derivative with random interest rates

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

[image]

For this question, I've worked out the payoffs at N=3 but I'm not able to understand how to calculate the the expectation of the terms inside. If anyone could tell me how to find the expectation of the terms in the square brackets then that would be very helpful. If we had expectation at time 1 of just V3 inside the square bracket then I know how to find that out but here V3 is being divided by (1+r1)(1+r2) and so I'm getting a bit confused when trying to find the expectation.

Could someone check my solution please.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You already have the process for $S$, yes?  So there are only finitely many possible states of the world at time $3$...where the interest rate history constitutes part of the start.  Just compute the expectation by hand (sum of payouts * probabilities).

Comment: Sorry, meant "state" instead of "start".

Comment: How would I work out the risk-neutral probabilities p and q? In the question the up and down factors aren't changing but the interest rate is, so when calculating p= (1+r-d)/u-d  what value of r would I use?

Comment: Just to clarify:  the asset is not itself correlated to interest rates, yes?  I mean...if this were the value of a forward swap or something then the process is more subtle.  But, assuming this is a generic stock or something, then you just have multiple trees, corresponding to the possible  values of $r$.

Comment: Phrased differently:  Where your constant interest rate process had two states at time $2$, you now have $6$...$S$ moves as it did before but you have an independent state variable for $r_2$.  Each of those states then evolves as per usual, using the value of $r_2$ associated with that state.

Comment: I've just added my working out, could you please let me know whether or not its correct.

Comment: sorry, my eyes aren't quite up to that.  But the shape of the calculation looks correct.  Like I say, unless the asset is linked to the motion of the rates, the trees essentially decouple.